# Set height of Img via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, height

I am currently running into a problem with my code. I am attempting to set the height of an image through JavaScript in a check that its less than 600 pixels. I have tried a plethora of alternatives to the general "this.height = 600" but none have resulted successfully. I am really hoping someone can help me fix this problem.

```
<div id="cursedframe">  
  <img src="" id="cursedimg">
</div>

<script>

function setImage() {
    var img = new Image();
    var images = [
        "bean.jpg",
        "xxx-edit-parallax/Images/xxx-5.jpg"
    ];

    var chosen = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

    img.onload = function(){

    if (this.height > 600) {
            console.log("more than");
            this.height = 600;
            console.log(img.height);
        } else {
            console.log("less than");
            this.height = "auto";
            console.log(this.height);
        }
    };

    img.src = chosen.toString();
    document.getElementById("cursedimg").src = img.src;
}   


</script>
```

It successfully passes the "if" but never actually sets the height.

**EDIT:** Unaware of the CSS property of `max-height` and `max-width` at the time. Was brought to my attention by Lain. Thank you

Comment: Cant you just set the `max-height` to 600px in css? Seems to be pretty much what you are doing here.

Comment: Owo. Thats a thing? Ah, Saviour! I think its safe to say I am oblivious to CSS

Comment: You never assign any load event to `document.getElementById("cursedimg")` by the way. Merely to a non DOM image called `img` which has no influence on your acutal shown image. You would need to add `document.getElementById("cursedimg").style.height = img.height + 'px';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier to use the css property `max-height`.

Just to show the actual flaw with the approach in javascript: you have to pass the height on to the actual image. Currently you merely set it to the `img` object yet never to the shown image `<img src="" id="cursedimg">`.

```js
var img = new Image();
var images = ['https://logosmarken.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Google-Logo.png'];
var maxHeight = 200; //REM: For my test image

img.onload = function(){
    if (this.height > maxHeight) {
        console.log("more than");
        this.height = maxHeight;
        console.log(img.height);
    } else {
        console.log("less than");
        this.height = "auto";
        console.log(this.height);
    };
    
    //REM: Here you need to assign the src along with the height
    document.getElementById("cursedimg").src = this.src;
    document.getElementById("cursedimg").style.height = this.height + 'px';
};

//REM: No need for toString() - it already is.
img.src = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
```

```html
<div id="cursedframe">  
  <img src="" id="cursedimg">
</div>
```

Even easier would be to not create a new object at all and just assign it as is:
`var img = document.getElementById("cursedimg");`

Answer (score 0):

By running the following code, you are assigning the only the src attribute to the img element

```
img.src = chosen.toString();
document.getElementById("cursedimg").src = img.src;
```

If you want to set the height and src of the image element using javascript,
you can do the following:

```
var image = document.getElementById("cursedimg");
if ( image.height > 600 ){
     image.height = 600;
}
else{
     image.style.height = "auto";     // since 'auto' is a styling value
}
image.src = chosen.toString();
```